# Unable to retrieve selected index from NSComboBox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

Im trying to get the selected index of a NSComboBox that has a datasource by using indexOfSelectedItem.

```
[combobox setUsesDataSource:YES];
[combobox setDataSource:dataSource];
[combobox selectItemAtIndex:1];
int idx =[combobox indexOfSelectedItem];
```

idx will always returns -1;

Getting the same results even when defining a internal list for the NSComboBox in InterfaceBuilder.

Is there any other way to retrieve the selected index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try calling `[combobox numberOfItems];` just to make sure that you have items in the list.

Additionally, calling `selectItemAtIndex:1` should fire an [NSComboBoxSelectionDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSComboBoxSelectionDidChangeNotification) that you can listen for to make sure it changes.

**Edit 1:** Also, did you make sure to select "Uses Data Source" on the "Attributes Inspector" (Command-1 shortcut key) for the ComboBox in Interface Builder? By default, it uses the internal list, which would conflict with the DataSource method that you are attempting to use.

**Edit 2:** Never mind about that previous comment, your code calls it explicitely.

Comment: Got it working now, i don't know what was wrong, might have done something wrong in IB.